# Metro Web Service on Weblogic 10.0

Tags: web-services, weblogic, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

hoping someone may be able to help us get over a configuration issue we are having with getting Metro (JAX-WS) web services running correctly on our Weblogic 10.0 application server.

Setup at the moment, a maven project in Eclipse and following the example provided @
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/11/jaxws-with-spring-and-maven-tutorial.html

We also looked at Glen Mazza work 
http://www.java.net/external?url=http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/deploying_metro_and_cxf_based

but all efforts so far have not worked.

I'm hoping someone may be able to provide us with a basic hello world maven project example of metro running on weblogic.

If its something you can help with, in the webapp project, our files are "GreetingService" and "GreetingServiceEndpoint" as provided in the example with the same src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml and applicationContext.xml

We have tried to define sun-jaxws.xml but continues not to work.

Also defined in the EJB project is a src\main\application\META-INF\weblogic-application.xml

Deployment is successful but getting the following error when I attempt to start the application "class: com.hp.kcs.webservices.jaxwsspring.endpoints.jaxws.SayHello could not be found "

Thanks for your help..

Comment: the jaxws package is usually generated by running wsgen.  Have you run that?  Is it wired into your Maven project as a plugin?

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I added the plugin to maven and I added the dependency  <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
                  <version>2.1.3</version>
              </dependency>  but get an error "Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jws/WebService".

Comment: Hi Jeff, finally got over the issue. The spring-web file had to be configured in the classpath. Last issue may require a new question but I'm seeing an issue when I have deployed and running the web service in WL10.0 - [JAM] Warning: failed to resolve class com.javacodegeeks.jaxwsspring.endpoints.GreetingServiceEndpoint..

Comment: I have an example here: https://www.samplecode.oracle.com/sf/projects/oracle-parcel-svc/ that has Spring Web Services wired with Maven and it works on WebLogic.  Feel free to check it out and compare.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. It could be permissions buts getting "no results found". Currently the EAR file is deployed on WL10 (finally). The generated JAXWS classes are in the war file under WEB-INF\classes but if I attempt "http://192.168.1.3:7001/webApp/GreetingService?wsdl", I get the following exception:class: com.hp.it.kcs.webservices.jaxwsspring.endpoints.jaxws.SayHello could not be found
 at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.getClass(RuntimeModeler.java:272)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processDocWrappedMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:566)

Comment: I think its a runtime issue but all the webservice-*.jar (no weblogic jar files) files are in the ear lib (there are no jar files in the webapp lib folder) but I'm able to overcome this; its proving much more difficult than we initially thought.